# Executing GMT wrapper scripts in Qt

Tags: ubuntu, qt4

I'm new to ubuntu and also to linux commands. GMT(generic mapping tool) commands are not running when i execute it in Qt.

I get an error `sh: psxy not found`

How to do this?

I tried this code:

```
Qprocess *proc
proc->start(./xy.gmt);
```

xy.gmt is my GMT wrapper script.

Comment: @user640762 Did you tried to use the absolute path to your script?

Answer (score 0):

1. **xy.gmt** script must be with executable flags (check this), or do `chmod +x ./xy.gmt`
2. You may try to add absolute path, for example:

   QString absPath = qApp->applicationDirPath();
   QProcess *proc;
   proc->start(absPath + "/xy.gmt");
3. Also try use shell in start() method, example: `proc->start("/bin/sh " + absPath + "/xy.gmt");